# Environment variables substitution in C

Tags: c, environment-variables, variable-substitution, envsubst

I have a string with the following content (UTF-8):

```
__$FOO ${FOO} ${FOO:def} ${FOO2:-тест}
```

And environment variable `FOO` with a value `test`. My C application should work like a GNU  `envsubs` - replace all `$FOO` or `${FOO}` entries with a `test` - nothing complicated. Expected result:

```
__test test test тест
```

But... How can I do this using C only? I can't use something like `exec` or external (dynamic) libraries (my app is statically linked for using in docker scratch).

I know about [envsubst from gettext](https://github.com/bennoleslie/gettext/blob/43ed71f3d9517aafbdfd4216fdfe8da4801f10a2/gettext-runtime/src/envsubst.c#L235-L277), but it does not support the default values, as a minimum.

I found libraries with all required features in Go - [stephenc/envsub](https://github.com/a8m/envsubst) and Rust - [stephenc/envsub](https://github.com/stephenc/envsub), but maybe anyone knows how I can do the same in C? I don't want to invent something that has probably already been invented.

```c
static char *envsubst(char *str) {
  // magic
}
```

Comment: I'd probably just write a custom state machine string parser. Any other features like `'single quoted $FOO'` prevents substitution? Nested `${var${FOO}}` substitution?

Comment: Static compilation does not, in itself, preclude using `exec`. But you can also write your own expansion logic, or copy the code from the `envsubst` utility, if GNU compatibility isn’t an issue for you.

Comment: If you can use `exec`, you might need to worry about whether the string is safe/clean: if an untrusted user might get it to be `"$(/my/path/naughty)"`, don't pass it to bash!

Comment: @aschepler Presumably one would pass it to `envsubst`. I’m not aware of any CVEs on that tool, and it should perform mere textual replacement, nothing more. (And anyway, when you’re programming in C, security is clearly not your top 1 priority.)

Comment: `I know about envsubst from gettext` `how I can do the same in C?` and envsubst is in C. You have to actually _write_ the code to implement what you want. What exactly do you expect from this forum? `How I can do this using C only?` Parse the input string, for every ${...}` sequence, find if it has default, if has, remember it, replace the `${...}` sequences with the environment value or by the default value, output. You ahve to write such code "using C only". With what _exactly_ are you having problem with? Do you know how to find a character, or a string, in a string?

Comment: There's `wordexp()`, but it does a lot more than just parameter expansion.

Comment: The standard `envsubst` command, both on Linux and macOS, does not support modifiers as shown in your example. The Go implementation does. Why not just reimplement the Go version in C? For that matter, why are you trying to support legacy POSIX shell syntax for this? It seems like there is a higher level question here. Supporting POSIX shell variable substitution is going to be really, **really**, hard. I'm willing to bet that even the Go implementation you linked to gets lots of corner cases wrong given the quirks of POSIX shell rules for parsing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find an answer, I decided to write my own parser. It has less functionality than I was looking for, but that was enough for my case:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "envsubst.h"

struct buffer {
        char *data;
        unsigned int len, cap;
};

static struct buffer *newBuf(unsigned int cap) {
    struct buffer *b = malloc(sizeof(struct buffer));

    b->data = malloc(cap * sizeof(char));
    b->cap = cap;
    memset(b->data, '\0', b->cap);

    return b;
}

static void emptyBuf(struct buffer *buf) {
    if (buf->len > 0) {
        memset(buf->data, '\0', buf->cap);
        buf->len = 0;
    }
}

static void writeInBuf(struct buffer *buf, const char c) {
    if (buf->cap <= buf->len + 1) {
        size_t newSize = buf->cap + 64; // growing size

        void *newAlloc = realloc(buf->data, newSize);

        if (newSize > buf->cap && newAlloc) {
            size_t diff = newSize - buf->cap;
            void *pStart = ((char *) newAlloc) + buf->cap;
            memset(pStart, '\0', diff);

            buf->data = newAlloc;
            buf->cap = newSize;
        }
    }

    buf->data[buf->len++] = c;
}

static void writeStringInBuf(struct buffer *buf, const char *str) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        writeInBuf(buf, str[j]);
    }
}

/**
 * Parse the string and replace patterns in format `${ENV_NAME:-default_value}` with
 * the values from the environment (or default values after `:-` if provided).
 */
char *envsubst(const char *str) {
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);

    if (strLen < 4) {
        return (char*) str;
    }

    struct buffer *result = newBuf(strLen);
    struct buffer *envName = newBuf(32);
    struct buffer *envDef = newBuf(32);

    enum {
            DATA,
            ENV_NAME,
            ENV_DEFAULT,
    } state = DATA, prevState = DATA;
    bool flush = false;
    unsigned int nested = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        // detect the state
        if (str[i] == '$' && str[i + 1] == '{') {
            i++;
            nested++;
            prevState = state;
            state = ENV_NAME;

            continue;
        } else if ((str[i] == ':' && str[i + 1] == '-') && state == ENV_NAME) {
            i++;
            prevState = state;
            state = ENV_DEFAULT;

            continue;
        } else if (str[i] == '}' && (state == ENV_NAME || state == ENV_DEFAULT)) {
            nested--;

            if (nested == 0) {
                i++;
                prevState = state;
                state = DATA;
                flush = true;
            }
        }

        const char c = str[i];

        // state processing
        switch (state) {
            case ENV_NAME:
                writeInBuf(envName, c);
                break;

            case ENV_DEFAULT:
                writeInBuf(envDef, c);
                break;

            case DATA:
                if (prevState == ENV_NAME || prevState == ENV_DEFAULT) {
                    char *envVar = getenv(envName->data);

                    if (envVar) {
                        writeStringInBuf(result, envVar);
                    } else if (envDef->len > 0) {
                        writeStringInBuf(result, envDef->data);
                    }

                    emptyBuf(envName);
                    emptyBuf(envDef);
                }

                if (flush) {
                    i--;
                    flush = false;

                    continue;
                }

                writeInBuf(result, c);
        }
    }

    free(envName->data);
    free(envName);

    free(envDef->data);
    free(envDef);

    char *data = result->data;
    free(result);

    return data;
}
```

And the tests:

```c
#include <assert.h>

// tests running: `gcc -o ./tmp/subs ./src/envsubst.c && ./tmp/subs`
int main() {
    putenv("Test_1=foo");
    putenv("__#Test_2=");

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("__$_UNSET_VAR_ ${_UNSET_VAR_} ${_UNSET_VAR_:-default value }"),
        "__$_UNSET_VAR_  default value "
    ) == 0);

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("${__#Test_2} ${__#Test_2:-foo}${_UNSET_VAR_:-def}${__#Test_2}"), " def"
    ) == 0);

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("${Test_1} ${Test_1:-def}${Test_1}"), "foo foofoo"
    ) == 0);

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("__$FOO ${bar} $FOO:def ${Test_1:-def} ${Test_1} ${_UNSET_VAR_:-default} bla-bla ${FOO2:-тест}${ABC} ${}${}"),
        "__$FOO  $FOO:def foo foo default bla-bla тест "
    ) == 0);

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("${_UNSET_VAR_:-${Test_1}}"), ""
    ) == 0);

    assert(strcmp(
        envsubst("aaa ${}} ${${} bbb"), "aaa } "
    ) == 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I use this? Maybe you have this somewhere out on Github?

Comment: @ds-bos-msk Yup! https://github.com/tarampampam/mustpl/blob/master/src/envsubst.c

Comment: Thanks Парамтамтам! You've got some pretty interesting projects btw!

Answer (score 0):

As you need a shell substitution, you can run implicitly a shell from your program through libc's services like `system()` or `popen()`. Those functions *fork/exec* a shell and the environment of the caller is inherited by the child process (`execve()` is used internally). This may appear cumbersome from a performance point of view but it does the job:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Non reentrant function as it returns a pointer onto a global static buffer
static char *envsubst(char *str) {
  FILE *f;
  static char cmd[256];
  int rc;

  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "echo %s", str);
  f = popen(cmd, "r");
  rc = fread(cmd, 1, sizeof(cmd), f);
  cmd[rc]='\0';
  pclose(f);

  return cmd;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac == 2) {
    char *p = envsubst(av[1]);
    printf("%s", p);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`popen()` calls `/bin/sh`. The previous works if `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/sh` points on bash and not on any esoteric shell like `dash` which does not understand this kind of variable substitution.

```
$ ./envp '__$FOO ${FOO} ${FOO:def} ${FOO2:-TECT}'
sh: 1: Bad substitution
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 août  20 20:30 /bin/sh -> dash
$ sudo rm /bin/sh
$ sudo ln -s bash /bin/sh
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 août  20 20:36 /bin/sh -> bash
$ export FOO=test
$ export FOO2=test2
$ ./envp '__$FOO ${FOO} ${FOO:def} ${FOO2:-TECT}'
__test test test test2
$ unset FOO2
$ ./envp '__$FOO ${FOO} ${FOO:def} ${FOO2:-TECT}'
__test test test TECT
$ unset FOO 
$ ./envp '__$FOO ${FOO} ${FOO:def} ${FOO2:-TECT}'
__ TECT
```

**PS**: Reading again your question, you mention that you can't use external libs as you are statically linked. So, I am not sure if you are able to use the libc and its `popen()/pclose()` services...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, as I told above - I can't use any external applications, because my app should work in an empty filesystem (eg.: docker scratch).